# Sccp layer problem during message transmission

Tags: wildfly, jboss7.x, ss7, jain-slee

I made a client-server association with ss7 but am receiving error of (Received SccpMessage for translation but no matching rule found )

INIT message and INIT-ACK have been exchange between client and server.

But onSending message i am receiving this error:

05:52:21,865 WARN  [org.mobicents.protocols.ss7.sccp.impl.SccpRoutingControl] (SLEE-EventRouterExecutor-17-thread-1) Received SccpMessage for Translation but no matching Rule found for local routing
SccpMessage=Sccp Msg [Type=-1 networkId=0 sls=1 incomingOpc=-1 incomingDpc=-1 outgoingDpc=-1 CallingAddress(pc=0,ssn=146,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=0350102, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=DefaultEncodingScheme[type=UNKNOWN, code=0]]) CalledParty(pc=0,ssn=146,AI=18,gt=GlobalTitle0100Impl [digits=0350101, natureOfAddress=INTERNATIONAL, numberingPlan=ISDN_TELEPHONY, translationType=0, encodingScheme=DefaultEncodingScheme[type=UNKNOWN, code=0]]) DataLen=103]

Can someone Help

Answer (score 1):

> Received SccpMessage for Translation but no matching Rule found

You need to create at least one sccp routing rule for the GT (Global Title) in the Called Party Address (0350101) and later you'll probably need another rule for the GT you've put in the Calling Party Address.

See [7.4.17. Create a new SCCP Rule](https://www.restcomm.com/docs/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_managing_sccp_rule_create) and [7.4.13. Create a new Primary/Backup address](https://www.restcomm.com/docs/core/ss7/SS7_Stack_User_Guide.html#_managing_sccp_addr_create)

See also:

- [smsc-starting-and-running-in-simulator-mode.adoc](https://github.com/RestComm/documentation/blob/master/core/src/main/asciidoc/tutorials/smsc-starting-and-running-in-simulator-mode.adoc)
- [ussd-how-to-configure-multi-tenancy-and-initiate-sctp-session.adoc](https://github.com/RestComm/documentation/blob/2f99ad575a61cc2e389f084595566ce2d8e1814e/core/src/main/asciidoc/tutorials/ussd-how-to-configure-multi-tenancy-and-initiate-sctp-session.adoc)
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mobicents-public/qwujAVVgbAQ

Comment: Thanks Vasil for the quick feedback i figured out, that because i am creating an sctp CLIENT-SERVER from scratch with jainslee was the problem.

Comment: when i am deploying my SBB on wildfly all layers get configured in the following directory [ /wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/ ] Except the layer were there is SccpRule get configured....... its seems like wildfly is ignoring this config file when i am deploying my SBB in [ /wildfly-10.1.0.Final/bin/MapLoadClientSccpStack_sccprouter2.xml ]     ........ So how can i force wildfly to read this file on deployement ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.